# Upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: upgrade, livedvd

I want to upgrade my Ubuntu 11.10, because I cannot install WvDial on it.
But In Ubuntu 13.10 WvDial is installed on Ubuntu 13.10 by default.
How can I upgrade my Ubuntu 11.10 to Ubuntu 13.10 via live disc ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly upgrade from 11.10 to 13.10. Using the Live DVD you can only do a fresh install of 13.10 (Back up suggested). If you really want an upgrade instead of a fresh install then you have to upgrade to 12.04->12.10->13.04->13.10 For more information visit https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend fresh install instead of upgrading. But before that fire-up liveCD and check if it's working as you would like it to.